# Solving a quadratic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, constraints, quadratic-programming

For given  $ a \in \Bbb{R}^n  , b \in \Bbb{R}$ solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2  $$ subject to: $${a}^Tx \ge b , x \ge 0   $$
*note:
This is a homework so a hint is most welcome.*

1. $L(x,\lambda) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \lambda({a}^Tx -b) $
2. Now setting the derivatives of the first term to $0$ leads me to $\forall i$ $ 2x_i = \lambda_ia_i $   but I cannot proceed now.

---

According to KKT conditons following has to hold $\forall_i$

1. $2x_i + \lambda a_i x_i \le 0$
2. $ x_i \ge0$
3. $x_i(2x_i + \lambda a_ix_i)=0$

Now,
Either $x_i =0$ or $\lambda= -2/a_i$
But this seems like I am making a mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You have to compliment your FOC of the Lagrangian with a complementary slackness condition.

---

The complementary slackness condition for your problem is 
$$ \lambda(a^Tx-b)=0$$ 
so either $\lambda=0$ (i.e., the constraint does not bind) or $\lambda>0$ and $(a^Tx-b)=0$  (i.e., the constraint binds).

**Edit:**

For the case $\lambda>0$ you have a system on $N+1$ linear equations in $N+1$ variables $\{\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n},\lambda\}$. Solve this system:

\begin{align}
 2 x_1 - \lambda a_1&=0 \\
 \vdots \\
 2 x_n - \lambda a_n&=0 \\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i &= b
\end{align}

Try to compute first $\lambda$ and then plug the value you find for it to FOCs.

Comment: This is what i am confused about, are these the complementary slackness conditions for the lagrangian? $ \forall_i \lambda_i x_i =0 $ and ${a}^Tx -b = 0$

Comment: I wrote a CS condition for your problem. It states that either constraint is binding or  the Lagrangian multiplier is $0$.

Comment: So if $\lambda = 0 \implies \forall_i x_i = 0$? If that's so, how do i handle if $\lambda > 0$ i can not solve the system since i don't know what $\lambda $ is.

Comment: See my newest edit. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: I can calculate it, but only if I use the assumption that $a_i \ne 0$,is that neccessary? sorry, my brain is just not working today...

Comment: If $a_i=0$ then straight from FOC you see that $x_i=0$.

Comment: But then, if $\forall_i a_i=0$ and $b \ne 0$ then we do not have a solution.

Comment: If $a_i$=0 for all $i$ then the constraint does not make sense unless $b<0$,and if $b<0$ then it does not matter anyway.